# Decode message Kafka-mqtt

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, mqtt

I receive messages from mqtt broker on a kafka topic using kafka-mqtt connector. Then i read this messages from kafka topic using a kafka consumer on spark. When I print the messages this is the result. How can i read correctly the messages?

This is the code for set consumer and create stream.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GestoreSoccorso").setMaster("local[2]");
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(500));

Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.0.4.215:9092");
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("ankioverdrive_v1_events");

JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
        KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                ssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
        );
```

Then this is the code that I use to read the messages from topic and print them.

```
stream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecordJavaRDD) throws Exception {
                consumerRecordJavaRDD.foreach(new VoidFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> stringStringConsumerRecord) throws Exception {
                        String stringa=stringStringConsumerRecord.value();
                        System.out.println(DEBUG+"DATI RICEVUTI -> "+ stringa);
```

Finally this is the output

```
DEBUG: DATI RICEVUTI ->     ܑ�՛Y
SKULL   �    unknown0%
```

Comment: How do you know MQTT data was serialized as a string?

Comment: I know it because i seen the code of mqtt message and it is a json convert in a string and then published.

Comment: If it were a string or JSON, you would not be seeing `ܑ�՛Y` characters. The message is either compressed, encrypted, or not JSON/plaintext. Can you show the output of `kafka-console-consumer`?

Comment: I can't see the output console now,  I can tomorrow. I seen the output this morning and on consumer console, there are a lot of lines of this type: x00/x00/.../SKULL/..../unknown/... I think that this is hex.

Comment: Looks like it, yes. Your topics have binary data that isn't entirely UTF-8 strings. In Spark, you could use `ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName()`, but you still need to determine how to decode the bytes, which can only be done by knowing what format they got into Kafka to begin with

Comment: Yes, in the data source is created a JSON with number and string, then all message is passed to stringfy and then publish on mqtt. Therefore I think that all message is a string (?)

Comment: Furthermore, when I print the message that I wrote in the question I use utf-8. Some value such as SKULL or unknown are correctly decode, therefore I think that for encode is used utf-8

Comment: strings within binary data still show up as strings. I don't know if/how mqtt would convert messages internally do its protocol, but your code isn't necessarily wrong. Can you consume from the MQTT data separately from Kafka? If you're using the Confluent MQTT connector, then it is probably Avro data.

Comment: I don't know how mqtt encode the messages. Anyway this is the output of kafka consumer execute with the console. This is part of the output. 
'b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xdc\x91\xe5\xd5\x9bY\nSKULL\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0eunknown\x040%\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xa6\x94\xe5\xd5\x9bY\nSKULL\x00\x00\xde\x01\xf0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10Straight\x040%\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\xf2\x9a\xe5\xd5\x9bY\nSKULL\x14.\x00\x00\x00\xe0M\xc2P\xc0\xd4\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0eunknown\x040%\x00''

Comment: in the configuration of mqtt-kafka connector there is this line 'connect.mqtt.kcql=INSERT INTO <DEVICE_TYPE>_events SELECT * FROM <DEVICE_TYPE>_<VERSION>/+/events WITHCONVERTER=`com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter`' i add maven dependecy at this class in my pom file in project spark and i configured the kafka consumer so:

Comment: kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.0.4.215:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer",com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

Comment: But i have this exception: ERROR StreamingContext: Error starting the context, marking it as stopped
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all that extra information. 1) I don't know the Landoop toolset 2) As you can see in that output, it's definitely not a plain string

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong values for parameters `key.deserializer` and `value.deserializer`.

Instead of

```
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
```

you need to pass

```
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
```

or simply

```
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
```

Comment: This is assuming MQTT data is actually a string

Comment: I try but it dosen't work. I belive that the problem is the encoding of the message. That is, i don't know as the message is encoded when mqtt send it on the kafka topic. However the message is a string. Can someone  tell me how can I see encoded used ? and How can i modify it?